# How do you localize a number of legacy globals without eval?

Tags: perl, global-variables, scope

I'm asking this question because I finally solved a problem that I have been trying to find a technique for in a number of cases. I think it's pretty neat so I'm doing a Q-and-A on this.

See, if I could use `eval`, I would just do this:

```
eval join( "\n"
         , map { 
             my $v = $valcashe{$_}; 
             sprintf( '$Text::Wrap::%s = %s', $_
                    , ( looks_like_number( $v ) ? $v : "'$v'" )
                    )
          }
        );
Text::Wrap::wrap( '', '', $text );
```

I even tried being tricky, but it seems that `local` localizes the symbol to the *virtual* block, not the physical block. So this doesn't work:

```
ATTR_NAME: while ( @attr_names ) {
    no strict 'refs';
    my $attr_name       = shift;
    my $attr_name       = shift @attr_names;
    my $attr_value      = $wrapped_attributes{$attr_name};
    my $symb_path       = "Text\::Wrap\::$attr_name";
    local ${$symb_path} = $attr_value;
    next ATTR_NAME if @attr_names;

    Text::Wrap::wrap( '', '', $text );

}
```

Same *physical block*, and I tested the package variables before and after being set, and they even showed the proper value on *their* time through the loop. But testing showed that only the *last* variable passed through retained its value for the call to `wrap`. So values only stayed localized *until* the end of the loop.

I think the solution is neat--even if arcane perl magick. But the end result is good because it means I can wrap legacy code that relies on package-scoped variables and be assured that the values set will be as short-lived as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Axeman, you idiot! The package stash is a *hash* too! This works:

```
local @Text::Wrap::{ keys %wrapped_attributes } 
    = \( values %wrapped_attributes )
    ;
```

This does the following:

1. It accesses the array slice of `Text::Wrap`'s symbol table and returns the named symbols.
2. Because it's a *symbol* and not a scalar, in order for perl to know the correct slot, you have to assign *references*. This is true for arrays and hashes as well, but we all know that their references are more common.
3. The `\( ... )` syntax passes back a reference for each item in the list.

So we localize each variable for each key in `%wrapped_attributes`, and we assign it a reference for each value there.

It's ugly and arcane, and it's hard to move it out of the way each time I need it--but with it, I can pre-specify and *delay* the localization to select places where I can put up Damien Conway's suggested barbed wire and danger signs.

If I'm going to use it, it has to be just that ugly where I use it.

Comment: It's ugly in that the package has globals as it's interface, that's for sure, and there is a lot going on there, making it a solution difficult to understand...but as far as a solution goes, that's pretty slick, I think. The fact that you can even do this in Perl is a testament to it's all around greatness.  If this were a C module you were working with, for example, you would have little to no way to protect those globals from being smashed without some TRUE ancient and arcane magicks!