# Is it proper to get and especially set Perl module's global variables directly?

Tags: perl, coding-style, encapsulation, perl-module

I was wondering what the best practice in Perl is regarding getting - or, more importantly, setting - a global variable of some module by directly accessing `$Module::varName` in case the module didn't provide getter/setter method for it.

The reason it smells bad to me is the fact that it sort of circumvents encapsulation. Just because I **can** do it in Perl, I'm not entirely certain I **should** (assuming there actually is an alternative such as adding a getter/setter to the module).

Comment: Just go for it. If they reject it so what. Worse things happen in life.

Comment: So *encapsulate* it. And you can use this as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540539/how-do-you-localize-a-number-of-legacy-globals-without-eval

Comment: @Robert - heh... ended up being false alarm as far as this case. It was Exporter, and upon further digging in preparation for the fix I discovered that there's an official workaround for what I was doing. The question still stands as it wasn't the only time the need to change a global arose for me, with CPAN or corporate modules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't violating encapsulation if the variable is part of the public API. (If it isn't that's another matter.)

I think direct access is preferable as it allows you to take advantage of dynamic scoping:

```
local $Module::varName = 42;
```

This makes conflicts with other code using `Module` less likely.

Comment: Agreed, I do things like `local $Data::Dumper::Maxlevels = 1;` all the time.

Comment: +1 amplifying the "if part of the public API"; if it is not, other users of this coyly named module might get unexpected behavior and turn on you with nasty teeth

Comment: what exactly would you consider "public API"? Whatever is in POD? If so, then no, the variable is NOT in POD.

Comment: @DVK If its documented you can use it.  If its not, you can use it but there's no guarantee next version it'll still be there or do what it did before.  Worse, there's no easy way to tell.  There's no error message for setting a global variable that didn't exist.  If you *must* use an undocumented global, if there's no other way to make your code work, add a test of the 3rd party module in your own test suite. Ensure that undocumented global is there and does its job.

Comment: @Schwern - Thanks. That's pretty much what I did for now.

Answer (score 2):

Global module variables were in vogue in the past, but considered "bad form" as an interface in Modern Perl.  It's important to recognize that Perl is 22-23 years old now, and styles and practices have changed. :)  Do note though that there are times when it's still appropriate, because there's some very nice features that come along with package variables.  It's as usual a matter of experience and practice to see what a good solution might be.

To understand the best use for package variables, you really need to understand how `local` works.  Check out [`local`'s perldoc help](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html).  Local lets you take a package variable like (as an example) `$My::Variable` in the package `My`, and create a [dynamically scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29) version of it.  Normally if you change `$My::Variable` in place, it will affect your entire program, and will persist.  For small programs, that might not be a big deal.  For large ones, this can have disastrous side effects.  `local` lets you make a temporary change to that variable, that's limited to your current scope.

Here's how it works:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

package My;

our $Variable = 5;

package main;

say $My::Variable; # prints 5
$My::Variable = 7;
say $My::Variable; # prints 7
{  # create a new lexical scope
    local $My::Variable = 10; # create a new dynamic scope for $My::Variable
                              # that will persist to the end of the lexical scope
    say $My::Variable;  # prints 10
}
say $My::Variable;  # end of the lexical scope for the localized
                    # $My::Variable, so prints 7 again
```

Effectively, it lets you use package variables in a safe way.  Unfortunately, not everyone knows about local, so they often clobber the global variable.  Documenting good use (eg, `local`) always helps.

A getter/setter with proper object encapsulation prevents a lot of this, but not always.  To make it work the way a local variable does, you'd have to do a lot of extra work.  The nicest thing about being able to localize a package variable is that you can do temporary changes very easily, say, for a debug variable.  Normally, you have to do a pattern like:

```
{
    my $current_variable  My::get_variable();
    $My::set_variable($new_value);

    # Do code work

    $My::set_variable($current_variable);
}
```

With local, this becomes:

```
{
    local $My::Variable = $new_value;

    # do code work
}
```

(Incidentally, I wish you could do this to lexical variables too, for the same reason...but you can't.)  So, for some things, package variables *can* make sense.  It depends on how you want to use it.  Things like

- Debugging Variables
- Global configuration that doesn't/shouldn't be changed often

However, if it's something that *does* need to be changed on a regular basis, like

- Regularly used variables (see the horrible interface for [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find))
- Temporary configuration
- "Object" variables

Basically, anything that needs to be modified more than once or in rare situations, or should otherwise be encapsulated into a generated object, then I'd avoid the package variable.

Comment: Saying Perl is 22 years old now makes *me* feel ancient. :(

Comment: Will be 23 in about 6 months! :D

Comment: `local` provides *dynamic* scoping, not *lexical* scoping. If you called a subroutine from inside the block it would see `$My::Variable` as 10, not 7. In retrospect, `local` should have been named `temp`, as it provides a temporary value for a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If the module doesn't provide an accessor, create one, use it, and send in the patch.